# LENOVO IdeaPad (U430 Touch) only charges up to 59%

Tags: 14.04, lenovo, battery, ideapad

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my LENOVO IdeaPad U430 Touch. How come the battery just charges up to 59%? I also have Win8 on another partion and it easily reaches 100%. 
I tried "[TLP](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-linux-advanced-power-management.html#installation)" but nothing changed. I've read some complaints from people who have a similar problem but they all have ThinkPads and there's a special modul for "TLP" where you can control the charging threshold.

What to do?

Comment: I have this exact ultrabook. Running Ubuntu-GNOME 14.04, but I know I do not have this problem. I get 100%, and I can run it down to nearly dead quite easily. I will take a look when I get home tonight and see if I can provide any insight. I want to figure out how to implement some of the battery life extending features of the Win8 drivers.

Comment: Some quick checking suggests laptop-mode-tools is going to be helpful. The TLP package looks pretty ThinkPad specific; I'd avoid it for now.

Comment: thanks for your reply. i read that it might have something to do with the power management in win8. i'll check that and will be back with more infos